# gdb - break in static functions

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have two static functions with same name in two different files.

```
radio.c
-------
static audio_call_back(...)
{
    // code to execute when audio from radio is acquired
}

mp3.c
-----
static audio_call_back(...)
{
    // code to execute when audio from mp3 player is acquired
}
```

They are executed by function pointer method.

With gdb, how can I have a break point in "audio_call_back" of mp3 file. By default if I run

```
(gdb) break audio_call_back
```

a break point is set up in radio.c file. How can I set break point in "audio_call_back" present in file mp3.c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[break filename:function](http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_29.html#SEC29) - mp3.c:audio_call_back

BTW, aren't you forgetting a return type?

Comment: the function signatures are the same.

Comment: @shri: So? You specify the file, and you're still forgetting a return type.